# Retrieve Gitlab Group members which has been assign to other Gitlab Group as Group

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Let me explain on the example. **Group1** and **Group2** have been created in the Gitlab.

For the **Group1** we assigned **2 users**.

For the **Group2** we assigned **4 users**.

To retrieve their data assignment details we can use API call based on the [List all members of a group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html#list-all-members-of-a-group-or-project-including-inherited-and-invited-members)

But if we assign the **Group2** to the **Group1** all 6 users will have access to the **Group1**, but using [API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html#list-all-members-of-a-group-or-project-including-inherited-and-invited-members) we will just retrieve direct (or inherited) users which are assign (not all users who has access to the **Group1**).

I would need to retrieve all users (6 people) data: **direct assignment** and **the users who has access via Group2 assignment**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer from Gitlab Support that they going to implement that feature in 16.11.X release.